# Opening & closing balances in powerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have a table for GL transactions for a whole period over the years. Now I need to develop a table in which I can see the opening balance and closing balance for each month.

Ex :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK2K8.png)

result I need is,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqmVF.png)

I tried "closingbalancemonth" function, but it gives the total of transactions done on the last day of the month as the closing balance.

Comment: What logic did you apply to arrive at your expected answer?

Comment: CBMonth = CLOSINGBALANCEMONTH(SUM(GL_GLPOST[TR_AMOUNT]), DATE_GL[Date])

Comment: Not sure if it is appropriate for your application, but you can obtain this output and format using the Query editor (Power Query).

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly what you want but at least it gives correct results.

Closing Balance

```
Closing Balance = 

            CALCULATE(sum(Transactions[GL Transactions]), 
                   filter(all(Transactions), 
                   EOMONTH(min(Transactions[date]),0)>Transactions[date]))
```

Opening Balance

```
Opening Balance = 

            CALCULATE(sum(Transactions[GL Transactions]), 
                   filter(all(Transactions), 
                   EOMONTH(min(Transactions[date]),-1)>Transactions[date]))
```

there are also two more calculated columns. one is for the report and one is for sorting..

for the report :

```
Year & Month = FORMAT(Transactions[date],"MMM - YY")
```

for sorting :

```
YearMonth = year(Transactions[date])&MONTH(Transactions[date])
```

[see also the attached sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zjBjsHLEuJcT6z6jQ_hDTHE93zL0a_6j/view?usp=sharing)

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this which has been solved on the Power Query side...

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bY3BCcAwDAN38TsRioObdJbg/dcoFAwq9GfuJPkcG7RmAww4/b1p2YqHiB4iNniVcG3cIvpna4Hr78kU7pJ3cBeflvkA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"GL account" = _t, date = _t, #"GL Transactions" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"date", type date}, {"GL Transactions", type number}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"date", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Eomonth", each Date.EndOfMonth([date])),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"GL account", "Eomonth"}, {{"Sum GL Transactions", each List.Sum([GL Transactions]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Closing Balance", each Function.Invoke((current as date,tb as table)=> 

List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(tb,each [Eomonth]>= List.Min(#"Grouped Rows"[Eomonth]) and [Eomonth]<=current)[Sum GL Transactions])

,{[Eomonth],#"Grouped Rows"})),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Opening Balance", each Function.Invoke((current as date,tb as table)=> 

List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(tb,each  [Eomonth]<current)[Sum GL Transactions])

,{[Eomonth],#"Grouped Rows"})),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom2",{{"Closing Balance", type number}, {"Opening Balance", type number}, {"Eomonth", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Sum GL Transactions"}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"GL account", "Eomonth"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Columns"
```

--->
[New Version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zjBjsHLEuJcT6z6jQ_hDTHE93zL0a_6j/view?usp=sharing)

[image: Balances]

Comment: @J1987 did this solve your issue ? If yes, please accept as an answer...